# ModernListView looks different on Windows and Android platform

Tags: android, windows, listview, delphi, firemonkey

I need your help.

Can someone explain to me why the appearance of ListView (I use ModernListView -> https://github.com/rzaripov1990/ModernListView) is different on Windows platform and Android platform. I am using Custom Style, StyleBook which is modified for Platform Default.
I use Delphi 10.4 CE, Update 2.

On Windows platform both Accessory (Type=More) and GlyphButton (ButtonType=Checkbox) in EditMode are visible.
On the Android platform, however, neither the Accessory (Type=More) nor GlyphButton (ButtonType=Checkbox) in EditMode is visible.

The source code of example can be found on github -> https://github.com/sax15/ListViewExample

Thanks for your help.

[image: Windows platform]

[image: Windows platform, EditMode]

[image: Android platform]

[image: Android platform, EditMode]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i didn't use Firemonkey in the past 2 years now(maybe even longer...), but from what i remember the controls will always look different between Windows and mobile.
sometimes also the behavior is different.
i think even when you set the controls to look native.

Edit -
Here are some useful link about styles and different devices :

https://books.google.co.il/books?id=euJDEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA164&lpg=PA164&dq=delphi+firemonkey+different+styles+in+different+devices&source=bl&ots=Xq55fI6L1z&sig=ACfU3U2mvWi7_DXu6hP2tca-WRJmNjEPIA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj5ho_K_qz4AhXUiP0HHZQVAIMQ6AF6BAglEAM#v=onepage&q=delphi%20firemonkey%20different%20styles%20in%20different%20devices&f=false

https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Working_with_Native_and_Custom_FireMonkey_Styles

https://www.fmxexpress.com/add-firemonkey-mobile-styles-into-your-desktop-apps-in-delphi-10-seattle-for-android-and-ios/

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: it's not a problem. the controls really do look and (sometimes) behave differently between the different devices and operating systems. especially when you set them to look Platform Default.

Comment: i edited my answer and added some useful links you can learn from

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Eitan Arbel, I realized that I had not changed Style for the Android platform. The Default style was not displaying correctly on the Android. Now I added the Style for the Android and everything works as it should.

I've also updated the example on github -> https://github.com/sax15/ListViewExample

THX Eitan